# Crystal report database issue in Delphi 11.2

Tags: plsql, crystal-reports, delphi-7, delphi-xe2

I am using crystal report 11 in delphi 7. Due to the unavailability of support from crystal report, I compiled the source code of crystal 11 in Delhi 11.2 and installed the components as part of migration to higher version. I encountered a series of problems like loading Crpe32.dll and opening print job and so on. Everything resolved but now stuck on oracle database connectivity . Upon selecting the .rpt file and calling the crpe.show giving me

“**error:756 failed to open the connection execute  Details : Database vendor code 12154”.**

This error is prompting while calling the “pestartprintjob“ through crpe.show method. Checked the oracle drivers and all but looks good on my Delphi 11.2 VM.Also crystal report is working fine in Delphi 7. Would highly appreciate a prompt response

Delphi 11.2 VM throwing this error and tried setting TNSnames.ora as well but in vain. Need to print the .rpt report in Delphi 11 using crystal report 11

Comment: If "Database vendor code 12154" means ORA-12154 , that's "TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified", and nothing to do with PL/SQL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825635/ora-12154-tnscould-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-specified-plsql-develop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. Actually, the difference between string and ansistring contributed to the issue. The connection parameters are not properly resolving as those are declared as String in the old version of the crystal report component. So Crpe32.dll could not make the connection. Changing them to ansistring resolved the issue. Thanks